# Is there a way to extend two classes with the same method that references super?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, inheritance, subclassing

I'm creating a subclass of the NodeJS `http.Agent` to get rid of the [queuing behavior](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/965ea9d586a49a42328f32aa339dc661e7ebf26d/lib/_http_agent.js#L295-L308) when it has reached the socket limit. I've overridden `addRequest` to track the number of concurrent requests per target, rejecting requests when no capacity is available to handle it.

The issue is that I also need to extend `https.Agent`, which [is itself a subclass](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/965ea9d586a49a42328f32aa339dc661e7ebf26d/lib/https.js#L124-L340) of  `http.Agent`, with the same behavior. If I create an `addRequest` function and assign it to the prototype of my subclasses of each agent, I'm unable to reference `super`. Is there a reasonably DRY way to do this?

The following code is excessively simple, but hopefully illustrates the problem.

```
class Original {
  addRequest(req) {
    console.log(req);
  }
  /* other stuff */
}
class ExtendedOriginal extends Original {
  /* various extensions of other stuff */
}

/* Custom */
class ConcurrencyLimitedOriginal extends Original {
  addRequest(req) {
    if (this.canAddRequest(req)) {
      super.addRequest(req); // super ref! Can only exist as a method, not a function
  }
  canAddRequest(req) {
    /* various logic */
    return true;
  }
}

class ConcurrencyLimitedExtendedOriginal extends ExtendedOriginal {
  /* DRY way to have same added logic as ConcurrencyLimitedOriginal? */
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a *mixin* class. In a language with multiple inheritance, you would define the mixin, then create subclasses of `http.Agent` and `https.Agent` that mix it in. But JS doesn't have multiple inheritance, so I think you have to define the two subclasses redundantly.

Comment: Yes, a mixin really is exactly what I need here. Unfortunate that JS doesn't support this behavior, looks like it may result in some slightly less maintainable code in this case.

Comment: JS does support mixins.  You just have to create it manually.   A search for "Javascript mixins" will give you plenty of examples.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that @jfriend00? Perhaps as a full answer to the question. The MDN docs contain only the generic definition of a mixin. I'm fine doing it manually, but I'm not clear on how that's actually possible.

Comment: To further elaborate on what's unclear, I created an object with property addRequest, and `Object.assign`'d it to the prototype of an otherwise empty subclass. But, this gives me a `[TypeError: (intermediate value).addRequest is not a function` error. Google does yield some resoults on how to do mixins, but my problem here is specifically the super reference which I'm unable to find a DRY path forward on. I'm open to the idea of one not existing, but if you had a specific implementation in mind in your message I would love to read it.

Comment: Mixins as a concept are very doable in Javascript and that's what my comment was posted to respond to since you said Javascript doesn't support mixins in your comment.  Here's a [tutorial](https://javascript.info/mixins) for one way of doing it.  I don't really follow your issue with `super`, but you can always call the parent class method implementation manually without using `super` just like we did before we had `super`.  `super` is just syntactic sugar.  You can still do it the old-fashioned way if you want.  `ParentClass.prototype.someMethod.call(this, ...args)` will bypass `super()`.

Comment: I was working on an answer, but your example code doesn't seem to illustrate the problem because everything in your example descends from Original, so you can put any common, shared methods in the `Original` class and it can call methods that have subclass overrides if it wants.

Comment: Thanks. I'm relatively new to JS and don't have a totally clear picture of how the syntactic sugar works. Your comment on the inheritance structure is exactly the issue I'm running into, though. `https.Agent` in the Node standard library inherits from `http.Agent`, with some additional logic to handle tls. My concurrency limiting needs to be applied to both agents, so the shared code can't refer to either `http.Agent.prototype` or `https.agent.prototype`. I can't actually put any shared logic in my real `Original` since it's part of the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this without mixins, due to issues with getting that approach to work discussed in comments. Instead, I took advantage of [Class Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class#examples) to instead more easily define two different subclasses with separate parentage but otherwise identical implementations:

```js
const createConcurrencyLimitedAgentClass = (parentAgent) => 
  class extends parentAgent {
    constructor(options) {
      super(options);
      // other init logic
    }
    // other method overrides
  };

const ConcurrencyLimitedHttpAgent = createConcurrencyLimitedAgentClass(Agent);
const ConcurrencyLimitedHttpsAgent = createConcurrencyLimitedAgentClass(HttpsAgent);
```

I'm not sure I'd call it the cleanest looking code ever, but I'm not convinced that there is a clean way to solve this given the existing class structure. Resulting structure from this approach looks like the following:

```
    http.Agent
    |        |
    |        https.Agent
    |        |
    |        ConcurrencyLimitedHttpsAgent
    |
    ConcurrencyLimitedHttpAgent
```

The two concurrency limiting agents are identical in implementation except they reference a different `super`.

Comment: This indeed is a clean and straightforward solution to the above described problem. In addition it does not claim/pretend to be a mixin based solution. It is a perfect example of when one should apply this inheritance based pattern/technique, which I personally prefer to label _**"dynamic sub classing"**_ or _**"dynamic sub typing"**_.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm creating a subclass of the NodeJS `http.Agent` to get rid of the queuing behavior when it has reached the socket limit

Don't create a subclass. Just use the existing class and pass the appropriate options, in particular `{maxTotalSockets: undefined}`.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work. If you review the http.agent source code, you'll see that if it reaches the socket cap, NodeJS stores the request in a queue to be handled when capacity is free. At sufficiently high request rates, a slow or broken dependency can outpace the timeout and result in an OOMKill of the app. https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/965ea9d586a49a42328f32aa339dc661e7ebf26d/lib/_http_agent.js#L295-L308

Comment: @spurrkins If `this.maxSockets` and `this.maxTotalSockets` are both `Infinity`, it won't reach that socket cap?

Comment: Wait actually both are already `Infinity` by default. What agent(s) are you using in your code and how do you construct them?

Comment: I unfortunately cannot show the exacts of my real code, but I do have the `maxSockets` param set in my actual application. This works generally, but I have experienced two cascading outages in a NodeJS middle tier because a dependency became extremely slow, resulting in queuing until it was OOMKilled.

What I'm really going for is a concurrency bulkheading pattern (and separately, circuit breakers). I am reducing concurrent requests against my dependencies, and failing fast if there is no capacity to serve a request that comes in.

Comment: Oh I see, so lifting the limit is not an option, you really want to override the behaviour of what should happen when the limit is hit.